# Laravel Eloquent Relationship 2 diffrent columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a relationship between 2 models.

I have 2 models: User & Synergy

The table users has a column named employee_id, employee_id has to match to the table Synergy on the column res_id

In the model user I added:

```
public function Synergy(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Synergy');
}
```

The model synergy:

```
class Synergy extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv1';
    protected $table = 'humres';
    protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

With this model the query is:

```
select top 1 * from [humres] where [humres].[user_id] = 1 and [humres].[user_id] is not null
```

but I want:

```
select top 1 * from [humres] where [humres].[res_id] = <COLUMN EMPLOYEE_ID> and [humres].[res_id] is not null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you need to explicitly state the column name for the relationships. Try this:

```
class Synergy extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv1';
    protected $table = 'humres';
    protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'res_id');
    }
}
```

And in the User model;

```
public function synergy(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Synergy', 'employee_id');
}
```

Use lowercase **s** for the `synergy` relationship.

Refer to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) for further details.